# Is there any way to print out all the ouput in a Python Tkinter textbox when I execute external python script?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm creating a GUI Software (using Python3 Tkinter) which executes a linux command when you press a button (command:  *python3 external_python_script.py* ), however I want all the outputs to be displayed inside my GUI Program (specifically inside the Textbox), because by default, all the outputs are displayed to the Terminal. Is there any way to solve this problem? Answers are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact requirements, I suggest you use the check_output funtion of the subprocess module. As shown in the following code:

```
import subprocess

from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

text = Text(root)
text.grid()

output = subprocess.check_output(['python3', 'python_script_name'], encoding='utf-8')
print(type(output))

for line, out in enumerate(output):
    text.insert("{}.{}".format(line, 0), out, "{}.end".format(line)) 

root.mainloop()
```

The python script name should be the full path to the python script, or otherwise make sure that the python scipt file is located in the same directory as the script that includes the check_output function call. The encoding='utf-8' ensures that the function returns a string that prints nicely in the text widget. Without the encoding keyword check_output returns a bytes-object which does not print nicely in the text-widget.

Comment: I tried to implemet the code you wrote into my scritp, however it shows error:

subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['python3', 'exploit.py']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

exploit.py is the script I want to execute. @dalanicolai

Comment: Are you sure that you typed it correctly? As it works perfectly here. You must give the full path to the exploit.py file, or otherwise you should make sure that the exploit file is located in the same directory as your script.

Comment: Im creating a GUI which based on the user output, it executes this argument (when the button is pressed): python exploit.py -h website.com -u /index.html
However the output when the script is executed must be shown in the textbox. I tried the script you said, but it said no file found "exploit.py". So I am stucked on this step.

Comment: As I indicated in my previous comment you should give the full path to your exploit.py script (i.e. python /FULL/PATH/TO/exploit.py -h website.com -u /index.html). If you do not give the full path then you have to make sure that the exploit script is placed in the same directory as the script from which you call the python command.